# How can I use if in request in Laravel API

Tags: laravel

When I use request in my API I have a condition that if supplier_id has a value of `1` then fields ID_cost and entry_Fee are `required` and if other than `1` they are `not required` How and where do I write this condition?

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'purchase_id'               => ['required'],
            'supplier_id'               => ['required'],
            'shipping_type'             => ['required'],
            'purchase_date'             => ['required'],
            'picture'                   => ['nullable'],
            
           
            'ID_cost'                   => ['?'],
            'entry_Fee'                 => ['?'],
          
            
        ];
    }

      public function validated($key = null, $default = null)
    {   

        return [
            'purchase_id'               =>$this->id,
            'supplier_id'               =>$this->supplier_id,
            'shipping_type'             =>$this->shipping_type,
            'purchase_date'             =>$this->purchase_date,
            'ID_cost'                   =>$this->ID_cost,
            'entry_Fee'                 =>$this->entry_Fee,
            'picture'                   =>$this->picture,
            
        ];
    }
```

Comment: did `required_if` not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

What about trying this way?

```
public function rules()
    {
        $rules = $this->rules;

        if (Input::get['supplier_id'] == 1 )
        {
            $rules['ID_cost'] = 'required';
            $rules['entry_Fee'] = 'required';
        }

        return $rules;
    }
```

Comment: But  what do you mean $rules = $this->rules; ?